# Android Studio dynamically loaded library

Tags: java, android, gradle, shared-libraries, dex

I have an Android application that dynamically loads a library using `DexClassLoader`. Until now the application and the library were developed in separate projects. I would like to unite the projects into a single project (two modules in a project?) but I am not sure how to achieve it with Android Studio/Gradle. Note, that I don't want to add a static dependency between the app and the library. The result I want to achieve is:

1. Both the application and the library are in the same project.
2. The building of the app and the library may be in two separate steps (but one step could be nice :D ).
3. The compiled library must be eventually an asset of the application and be bundled in the resulting APK; i.e., not statically compiled into the application but be a stand-alone file in the APK.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xiaomi's answer gave a good direction, but the eventual solution was somewhat different.

### Solution overview

The project is going to contain two modules: one for the application and one for the library. The app module will depend on the library so the library will be built before the app. When the JAR file is ready, it will be converted into DEX and copied into the app's assets library. The build activity of the application will automatically bundle the assets folder in the final APK.

### Step-by-step solution

1. If it isn't already there, include the library module in the project settings file `settings.gradle`:

   ```
   include ':app', ':libmynewlibrary'
   ```
2. Add the dependency in the `build.gradle` of `app` module:

   ```
   dependencies {
       ...
       compile project(':libmynewlibrary')
   }
   ```
3. Now the tricky part. We want to add a custom action immediately after the JAR is created. Luckily Android Gradle plugin has a predefined task "jar" - it builds the JAR obviously. We will just add something to it in the lib's `build.gradle`. Notice that the task is implicit and isn't in the gradle file at all. We are just expanding it by adding `doLast` to it:

   ```
   jar {
       doLast {
           exec {
               executable "dx"
               args "--verbose", "--dex", "--output=../app/src/main/assets/mynewlib.dex", "build/libs/libmynewlib.jar"
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bring your module into your project, you can edit in your project the file `settings.gradle` to include the module and to give its path.

```
include ':app' //your project module name
include ':library' //your imported module name
project(':library').projectDir = new File("/<path_to_module_library>/other_project/library")
```

Then the module will appear into your project.

If you go to your project gradle file (E.g.: build.gradle), you can now include your module as your project dependency.

```
dependencies {
...
   compile project(':library')
...
}
```

**Edit**

If you just want to automatically copy your jar from your library to your project's assets folder, you can simply define a [gradle task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html) in your library build.gradle like :

```
task copyTask(type: Sync) {
    from '/<path_to_your_jar>/classes.jar'
    into '/<path_to_your_project>/app/assets/'
}
```

This will copy your jar to your assets folder.

To use it when you are compile your code, you can add this task into the Run/Debug Configuration.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I don't want the library module to be statically compiled into my APK; I want it to be added as an asset, so I can load it manually later.

Comment: @FireAphis Ah I see. So answer 1 and 2 are ok, except that the `compile project` should just put the module apk (or jar) into the assets folder, right ?

Comment: The first step looks correct and I indeed want the jar in the assets folder. But adding it to the dependencies, won't it statically link the jar into the application? I want to avoid that. In general, stating the dependency is less important - I can manage without it. But how do I make gradle copy the jar into the assets?